# Table of content shows incorrect page number of reference

Tags: hyperref

I add the "Reference" section into my table of content using the following command: 
`\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{References}`

However, the page number of Reference shown in table of content is incorrect, and is 1 less than the real page number.

For example, if in the table of content, it shows:
`References          114`
Then Reference actually starts from page 115.

How should I fix this error? Thank you.

Comment: The page number is correct and shows the page where you added the `\addcontentsline` command.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: Now I understand, thank you. But how should I add Reference to TOC?

Comment: You should use `\bibname` instead of 'References', this will be easier to change later on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work for normal cases

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblio.bib}   % Is on 'every' TeX system 
%\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[linktocpage]{hyperref}


\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{First}
\cite{Lam94}
\blindtext[5]
\chapter{Second}
\blindtext[10]

\cleardoublepage
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\bibname}
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

**Edit** Better version -- let `biblatex` do the addition with the `heading=bibintoc` option of `\printbibliography`

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblio.bib}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[linktocpage]{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{First}
\cite{Lam94}
\blindtext[5]
\chapter{Second}
\blindtext[10]

\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc]
\end{document}
```