# Why the Index section page number is wrong in ToC?

Tags: table-of-contents, page-numbering

I have a problem with the number page of Index  in ToC: is the same as the bibliography.

[image: toc problem]

How can I fix it? The actual page number of Index must be 365, not 363 because in the page 363 is the bibliography.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Did you run twice the pdflatex command?

Comment: Yes, I did it.  I run twice the makeindex command too.

Comment: Please check the answers here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/74439/table-of-contents-incorrect-page-numbering to see if something there helps

Comment: Withou seeing the code that reproduces that behaviour, i guess you are adding yhe toc entry manually. If so, place `\cleardoublepage` right before that manual entry.

Comment: Possible solutions to add a `\cleardoublepage` before `\addcontentsline` (if you have one) and `\printbibliography` after these commands or after the first one (if you don't use the second). Other solution if first doesn't work try `\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc]` to print the bibliography. (First solution the link I added before, Second here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/238435/table-of-content-shows-incorrect-page-number-of-reference). If some of these solves your problem let as know to mark the question as a duplicate. If not please add a MWE that demonstrates the problem

Comment: A last solution to check is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/782187/latex-table-of-contents-links-to-wrong-section, but it is better to try `\cleardoublepage` instead of `\newpage` of the solution accepted there.

Comment: Hi, Koleygr.  Adding \cleardoublepage before \addcontentsline worked perfectly!!!!!  Now, I want to know how \cleardoublepage works and why it was a possible solution.

Comment: `\cleardoublepage` says to the compiler that on the specific point the page have to end (and for books and other two-sided documents says to start from next odd page). Sometimes is needed from bibtex to fix the page numbers, since bibtex is running with separate command and don't let always the rest of latex document to understand that there have been made a new start of text (it is somehow hidden in the aux file). Sure my  grossly explanation can be improved. I am open to delete it if someone explain it with a better way to you.

Comment: OfF-topic: I saw that you have some unanswered questions that solved in comments. It would be nice from you to write there the answer that helped you to solve the problem (so that the community will be helped too by your questions). Just suggesting because I saw you haven't think to do it. But it is what have to be done if none else answers.

Comment: @Fabio: Index is the wrong term here (it is in Spanish) but this is an English site so it is named `Table of Contents` or `ToC`, that's why I removed the completely irrelevant tag `makeindex`